# AngularJS: $decorator binding new variables to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using a decorator to add a variable to the isolated scope of a directive. But somehow, it doesn't work and I tried almost everything.

The exactly directive is one of angular-ui:

```
.directive('accordionGroup', function() {
  return {
    require:'^accordion',         // We need this directive to be inside an accordion
    restrict:'EA',
    transclude:true,              // It transcludes the contents of the directive into the template
    replace: true,                // The element containing the directive will be replaced with the template
    templateUrl:'template/accordion/accordion-group.html',
    scope: {
      heading: '@',               // Interpolate the heading attribute onto this scope
      isOpen: '=?',
      isDisabled: '=?'
    },
    ...
})
```

The $decorator code, which I use to change the template and add a new variable is:

```
mainModule.config(['$provide', function ($provide){

    $provide.decorator('accordionGroupDirective', function($delegate) { 
          var directive = $delegate[0];
          directive.templateUrl = "views/parts/accordion-unit.html";
          angular.extend(directive.scope, { index:'@' });
          return $delegate;
    });
}]);
```

Then, in the  I add: `index="$index"` and in the template I use it typing `{{index}}`, but always undefined...

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I just ran into this as well. The decorator approach used to work as recently as `1.3.0-beta.13` but no longer works in 1.3.8 for me. What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed that this is a bug in Angular 1.3.x: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10149

The current workaround is to use `.$$isolateBindings` on the directive instead of `.scope`. Here's the workaround for your code:

```js
mainModule.config(['$provide', function ($provide){

    $provide.decorator('accordionGroupDirective', function($delegate) { 
          var directive = $delegate[0];
          directive.templateUrl = "views/parts/accordion-unit.html";
          directive.$$isolateBindings.index = {
              attrName: 'index',
              mode: '@',
              optional: true
          };
          return $delegate;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I don't understand why a great framework such as angular still have these kind of bugs and other that I've found. Cheers.